# Hide inputText on lost focus with p:inplace

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

my form looks like that:

```
        <p:inplace>  
            <h:inputText id="description" value="#{cc.attrs.description}" /> 
        </p:inplace>
```

When the user clicks into the Text of the p:inplace the inputText will be shown to edit the value.

How can I hide the inputText or the p:inplace when the user clicks somewhere else or the control it self lose the focus.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `blur` event over the `inputText`, passing an id value to it:

```
<p:inplace widgetVar="basic_#{cc.id}">
    <p:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.description}" id="description">
        <p:ajax event="blur" oncomplete="basic_#{cc.id}.hide();" />
    </p:inputText>
</p:inplace>
```

Comment: This answer would be nicer if it took into account the fact that this is part of a composite component and thus could be included multiple times in the same view and thus could cause collisions in `widgetVar` name. The solution is: include something unique like `#{cc.id}` or so in widget var name like so `widgetVar="basic_#{cc.id}"` and reference it like so `oncomplete="basic_#{cc.id}.hide()"`.

Comment: @BalusC true! I didn't even see it was a composite... Updated ;-)